# ChartObjects Add VBA mehtod

Tags: excel, vba, charts, automation

I am creating Macro in VBA, and I need to include a graph in a worksheet, but ChartObjects.Add method does not work on my computer. At first, it worked, until yesterday morning, when it suddenly stopped working. If I try to use it on my colleague's computer it works fine, but on mine it does not work at all.

I tried to run this simple macro, just to see if the command works:

```
Sub test()
    Dim chart1 As ChartObject
    Set chart1 = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects.Add(300, 300, 300, 300)
End Sub
```

and I got the error "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'Add' of object 'ChartObjects' Failed"

Then I modified a bit the code for this one:

```
Sub test()
    Dim chart1 As ChartObject
    Set chart1 = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, Top:=300, Width:=300, Height:=300)
End Sub
```

and I got "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Automation error Unspecified error".

I have already tried disconnecting and reconnecting from office, uninstalling and reinstalling but it did not work out. My Excel has the same exact parameters and add-ins as the one of my colleague, for who it works. The sheet and the file are not protected.

I have been working on this the last two days but did not find any solution, so I am looking for help if anyone has a suggestion.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you manually add a chart in that workbook? If you turned off display of objects in that workbook, your code would error and you wouldn't be able to manually add a chart.

Comment: Yes I can add it manually and even delete it with a macro. I just cannot add it using a macro.

Comment: Does it fail in all workbooks?

Comment: Yes it does in any workbook with any macro

Comment: What if you run Excel in safe mode? (hold down Ctrl key while starting Excel)

Comment: It works well in safe mode, thank you! But it still does not work in standard mode, I wonder why...

Comment: I also find a way to make it work using "On Error Resume Next" command

Comment: If it works in safe mode, then the problem is one of your startup files in Excel (add-in, template or macro workbook).